# Web browser that can disable images and flash

Tags: browser

I'm looking for a minimal web browser (or web browser + extensions) that can easily disable images and flash to increase browsing speed.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Pretty sure all browsers can do this, check the settings.  Also, look into FlashBlock.

Answer (score 3):

Chromium browser is Chrome without all the fluff packaged by Google. You can get the latest nightly builds [here](http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/index.html). The settings are similar to Chrome, should you want to use Chrome instead of Chromium.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[Lynx](http://lynx.isc.org/) is a text web browser. No images, no flash, no multimedia, no annoying audio on myspace pages, probably no myspace pages either...

Comment: I prefer [Links](http://links.twibright.com/) :-P

Comment: Links only runs in Windows under Cygwin, a decidedly awkward requirement if you don't already use this for something else. Lynx is already compiled Win32 and so shouldn't require the Cygwin environment.

Comment: That's assuming he's running Windows :-P